# Using google new billing client with jetpack compose and inject activity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, in-app-billing

I am using google billing library v5 with jetpack compose.
in order to launch a billing flow, i need to pass the activity:

```
// Launch the billing flow
val billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams)
```

but I call the billing client from a `viewmodel`, and the `viewmodel` itself is being injected with hilt to the composable screen:

```
fun PremiumScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    screenTitle: String,
    viewModel: PremiumViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
   ...
}
```

I wonder how can I pass the `activity` object to the viewmodel?
in google code lab they pass the activity object to the composable like so:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            BasicsCodelabTheme {
                MainNavHost(viewModel = viewModel, activity = this)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if this is a good practice that I will now hold a reference to the activity and pass it all the way until the viewmodel?
is there a different way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One additional option will be to get a reference of the containing activity from the composable function. For instance:

```
@Composable 
fun PremiumScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    screenTitle: String,
    viewModel: PremiumViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   val activity = context.findActivity()
   viewModel.launchBillingFlow(activity = activity)
}

fun Context.findActivity(): Activity {
    var context = this
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is Activity) return context
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    throw IllegalStateException("message")
}
```

Comment: is it considered as the best practice to implement it that way?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I use is to pass the MainActivity as a localComposition across the entire app. This approach should only be used when you follow a single activity architecture else it may lead to memory leaks.

```kotlin
val LocalActivity = staticCompositionLocalOf<ComponentActivity> {
    error("CompositionLocal LocalActivity not present")
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalActivity provides this@MainActivity){
              BasicsCodelabTheme {
                  MainNavHost(viewModel = viewModel, activity = this)
              }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Now your main activity is available throughout the composable functions.

```kotlin
@Composable 
fun PremiumScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    screenTitle: String,
    viewModel: PremiumViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
   val context = LocalContext.current

   val activity = LocalActivity.current
   viewModel.launchBillingFlow(activity = activity)
}
```

I find this useful as the activity object is still being used in most of the android libraries. Hopefully, in the future, there will be a compose-optimized google play billing API, but this is the best I can think of.